# How do I set a threshold using a user's input?

Tags: java, pi, threshold, decimalformat

I'm not really sure how to set a threshold value or how I would do so using the input of a user? Would I use DecimalFormat? If so, how would I save the user's input into DecimalFormat?

Part 2: Rewrite the program so the user specifies the threshold and loops until the approximation is within this threshold for the value of Math.PI, displays the value of Math.PI, resulting value, and the number of iterations it took to reach it.

Sample output:

What is the threshold you wish to use: .000001

Math.PI:     3.141592653589793

pi:          3.1415936535887745

Number of iterations: 1000001

This is the code I have from the first part that is meant to be rewritten:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    //define
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        double pi = 0.0; 
    
        System.out.println("How many iterations would you like to do: ");
        int n = scnr.nextInt();
        
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            
            pi += (Math.pow(-1,i) * 4.0) / (2.0 * i + 1);
            
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("pi: " + pi);
        
    }


    
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am misreading the question but isn't it asking you loop until the difference between your calculated `pi` and Math.PI is within a threshold?  Tehn you output how many iterations it took (i.e the value of `i`)

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to change the while loop condition. Rather than loop until you reach a certain amount of iterations, you loop until your calculated PI value is within a certain amount. For example:

```
while (Math.abs(Math.PI - pi) > threshold) {
```